# Remove post title input from edit page

Tags: posts, title

I'd like to remove the post title input on a (cpt) post edit page (backend) based on user's capabilities.

I have already found [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015655/how-to-disable-pages-title-in-wp-admin-from-being-edited) dealing the problem. However, the solution in involves editing the WordPress core files. I don't like it that way.

Is it possible to achieve the hiding (or removing) with a plugin? Currently I do not know or do not see how the plugin should hook into WordPress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this  :

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_110427_hide_title');
function wpse_110427_hide_title() {
 if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
     remove_post_type_support('post', 'title');

}
```

This would hide title for subscriber.
Replace 'post' with your custom post type

Comment: That question was too easy for you. works like a charme!

Comment: It's subscribEr instead of subscribOr (see your code above)

Comment: true. Sorry for that I edit.

Comment: In Wordpress 5.x admin, the update button in admin displays as disabled when you remove the post title field with `remove_post_type_support('post', 'title');`. In my specific case, I also needed to remove the default editor for the post content. When doing `remove_post_type_support($this->custom_post_type_name, 'editor');`, the fancy (disabled) Wordpress admin update button was gone and an Update button displayed with a simpler design, to the right sode of the screen. This solution incidentally worked for me, but I don't know what I need to do if I want to remove the title only.