# Hide post title input for all roles except admin

Tags: admin, post-meta, actions, title, customization

How would this function need to be updated to exclude the admin?

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_110427_hide_title');
function wpse_110427_hide_title() {
 if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
     remove_post_type_support('post', 'title');

}
```

[Remove post title input from edit page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110427/remove-post-title-input-from-edit-page)

Comment: Try adding `! in_array('administrator', get_userdata($current_user->ID)->roles )` in the condition. Don't forget to call `global $current_user` first..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried following code and its working. You need to place this in your theme's `funtions.php` file. Let me know how it goes :)

```
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_only_post_title');
function admin_only_post_title() {  
if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))
     remove_post_type_support('post', 'title');

}
```